# Identify the singularity in this ..

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> $\frac {\sin^2z}{z^2} $

What kind of singularity is present in this ?

My take on this is that, the limit at $z = \infty$ , is $0\,\,$.So, limit is finite.Thus, there should be no essential singularity at $z = \infty$. But,the answer says there is an essential singularity at that point. Also, the series expansion gives no principal part.Thus, shouldn't there be a removable singularity at z=0 ?

Kindly help. I've got a test tomorrow. Confused. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why* is the limit $0$ as $z\to\infty$? Keep in mind that the sine function is *not bounded* on the complex plane as it is on the reals.

Let $f(z)=\frac{\sin^2(z)}{z^2}.$ Then $$\begin{align}f(z) &= \frac{1-\cos 2z}{2z^2}\\ &= \frac1{2z^2}\left(1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(2z)^{2n}\right)\\ &=\frac1{2z^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}4^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2(-4)^{n-1}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-2}\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2(-4)^n}{(2n+2)!}z^{2n},\end{align}$$ so $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0,$ since $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=1.$

Now, note that $f(\frac1z)$ readily has an essential singularity at $z=0,$ meaning that $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=\infty.$

Comment: Oh ,my mistake ..Nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

**hints:**

Notice that $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin^2z}{z^2}=1$$